Execute fetch call inside map function (or for loop)
I am trying to iterate over an array of objects, and depending on the content of some of those objects I need to execute a fetch function, wait for the result before updating the new array.
Here is my js:


const allPosts = [
{
    "type": "image",
    "is_blocks_post_format": true,
    "blog_name": "jessicaharbydotcom",
    "id": 744489834793566200,
    "id_string": "744489834793566208",
    "is_blazed": false,
    "is_blaze_pending": false,
    "can_blaze": false,
    "post_url": "https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/post/744489834793566208/shield-2018-wax-display-case-light-shield-is-a",
    "slug": "shield-2018-wax-display-case-light-shield-is-a",
    "date": "2024-03-09 16:13:54 GMT",
    "timestamp": 1710000834,
    "state": "published",
    "format": "html",
    "reblog_key": "4O3x5WWb",
    "tags": [
        "shield"
    ],
    "note_count": 0,
    "title": "",
    "body": "<div class=\"npf_row\"><figure class=\"tmblr-full\" data-orig-height=\"4032\" data-orig-width=\"2640\"><img src=\"https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg\" data-orig-height=\"4032\" data-orig-width=\"2640\" srcset=\"https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s75x75_c1/eb876d72933b6138eeba73ca59499c3809975b61.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s100x200/21f86af6b60e44ba7d90090281dc1a1461494805.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s250x400/eba73e6b36bf95f9473e9276592794923583d9de.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s400x600/f202a41604edd3e6cfeee2f9457620bbc87accff.jpg 393w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s500x750/3def886512d22590bb2b72396d147cb8007ccd46.jpg 491w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s540x810/d83eb22083d9dafb4feae95e2f4a2ca0553e0ae8.jpg 530w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg 629w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s1280x1920/1c03d83fdad14df8334745de77595cd9d2215ce7.jpg 1257w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s2048x3072/ee6e6bf1448c6304fbf6cbed93062b9ca520baf3.jpg 2011w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px\"/></figure></div><p>Shield<br/>2018<br/>Wax, display case, light</p><p>Shield is a meditation on masculinity and power. The tiles are wax casts of the substantial belt buckle once belonging to the artist&rsquo;s grandfather, who was a Chicago Police Sergeant investigated in the 1970s as part of a ring of police shaking down motorists for payoffs. While eventually granted immunity from prosecution by the state, he was indicted, along with two fellow policemen, for perjury by a grand jury for lying about his involvement.</p>",
    "reblog": {
        "comment": "<p><div class=\"npf_row\"><figure class=\"tmblr-full\" data-orig-height=\"4032\" data-orig-width=\"2640\"><img src=\"https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg\" data-orig-height=\"4032\" data-orig-width=\"2640\" srcset=\"https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s75x75_c1/eb876d72933b6138eeba73ca59499c3809975b61.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s100x200/21f86af6b60e44ba7d90090281dc1a1461494805.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s250x400/eba73e6b36bf95f9473e9276592794923583d9de.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s400x600/f202a41604edd3e6cfeee2f9457620bbc87accff.jpg 393w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s500x750/3def886512d22590bb2b72396d147cb8007ccd46.jpg 491w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s540x810/d83eb22083d9dafb4feae95e2f4a2ca0553e0ae8.jpg 530w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg 629w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s1280x1920/1c03d83fdad14df8334745de77595cd9d2215ce7.jpg 1257w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s2048x3072/ee6e6bf1448c6304fbf6cbed93062b9ca520baf3.jpg 2011w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px\"></figure></div><p>Shield<br>2018<br>Wax, display case, light</p><p>Shield is a meditation on masculinity and power. The tiles are wax casts of the substantial belt buckle once belonging to the artist’s grandfather, who was a Chicago Police Sergeant investigated in the 1970s as part of a ring of police shaking down motorists for payoffs. While eventually granted immunity from prosecution by the state, he was indicted, along with two fellow policemen, for perjury by a grand jury for lying about his involvement.</p></p>",
        "tree_html": ""
    },
    "can_reply": false,
    "display_avatar": true
},
    {
    "type": "video video-embed",
    "is_blocks_post_format": true,
    "blog_name": "jessicaharbydotcom",
    "id": 744485994035904500,
    "id_string": "744485994035904513",
    "is_blazed": false,
    "is_blaze_pending": false,
    "can_blaze": false,
    "post_url": "https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/post/744485994035904513/referendum-ask-me-how-do-i-feel",
    "slug": "referendum-ask-me-how-do-i-feel",
    "date": "2024-03-09 15:12:51 GMT",
    "timestamp": 1709997171,
    "state": "published",
    "format": "html",
    "reblog_key": "qL2EmJnA",
    "tags": [
        "referendum"
    ],
    "short_url": "https://tmblr.co/ZXen9PfKyX4kmu01",
    "summary": "Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)",
    "should_open_in_legacy": false,
    "recommended_source": null,
    "recommended_color": null,
    "note_count": 0,
    "title": "",
    "body": "<p class=\"npf_link\" data-npf='{\"type\":\"link\",\"url\":\"https://vimeo.com/181950781\",\"display_url\":\"https://vimeo.com/181950781\",\"title\":\"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)\",\"description\":\"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) uses footage from the classic film A Matter of Life and Death to create a new narrative. The film speaks d\",\"site_name\":\"Vimeo\",\"poster\":[{\"media_key\":\"ad17645e0781329536708048ee806163:9100d8a78851c197-1c\",\"type\":\"image/webp\",\"width\":1920,\"height\":1080}]}'><a href=\"https://vimeo.com/181950781\" target=\"_blank\">Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)</a></p><p>Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) <br/>2016<br/>Single channel video</p><p>Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) uses footage from the classic film A Matter of Life and Death to create a new narrative, speaking directly to the viewer as the men onscreen debate and decide important matters, failing to provide answers to the direct questions posed. </p>",
    "reblog": {
        "comment": "<p class=\"npf_link\" data-npf='{\"type\":\"link\",\"url\":\"https://vimeo.com/181950781\",\"display_url\":\"https://vimeo.com/181950781\",\"title\":\"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)\",\"description\":\"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) uses footage from the classic film A Matter of Life and Death to create a new narrative. The film speaks d\",\"site_name\":\"Vimeo\",\"poster\":[{\"media_key\":\"ad17645e0781329536708048ee806163:9100d8a78851c197-1c\",\"type\":\"image/webp\",\"width\":1920,\"height\":1080}]}'><a href=\"https://vimeo.com/181950781\" target=\"_blank\">Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)</a></p><p>Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) <br>2016<br>Single channel video</p><p>Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) uses footage from the classic film A Matter of Life and Death to create a new narrative, speaking directly to the viewer as the men onscreen debate and decide important matters, failing to provide answers to the direct questions posed. </p>",
        "tree_html": ""
    },
    "can_reply": false,
    "display_avatar": true
},
{
    "type": "video video-embed",
    "is_blocks_post_format": true,
    "blog_name": "jessicaharbydotcom",
    "id": 744393264438837200,
    "id_string": "744393264438837248",
    "is_blazed": false,
    "is_blaze_pending": false,
    "can_blaze": false,
    "post_url": "https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/post/744393264438837248/affirmation-2016",
    "slug": "affirmation-2016",
    "date": "2024-03-08 14:38:57 GMT",
    "timestamp": 1709908737,
    "state": "published",
    "format": "html",
    "reblog_key": "jniGZGhJ",
    "tags": [
        "affirmation"
    ],
    "short_url": "https://tmblr.co/ZXen9PfKdRha4W00",
    "summary": "Affirmation (2016)",
    "should_open_in_legacy": false,
    "recommended_source": null,
    "recommended_color": null,
    "note_count": 0,
    "title": "",
    "body": "<p class=\"npf_link\" data-npf='{\"type\":\"link\",\"url\":\"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy\",\"display_url\":\"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy\",\"title\":\"Affirmation (2016)\",\"description\":\"Affirmation (2016) uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton wa\",\"site_name\":\"Vimeo\",\"poster\":[{\"media_key\":\"cd78c9656df6b9381417c980464efff7:86fa2ab3c65a5863-70\",\"type\":\"image/webp\",\"width\":1920,\"height\":1080}]}'><a href=\"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy\" target=\"_blank\">Affirmation (2016)</a></p><p>Affirmation <br/>2016<br/>Single channel video</p><p>Affirmation uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton was badly injured shooting this portion of the film and chose to keep the jarring moment of impact in the finished comedy.</p>",
    "reblog": {
        "comment": "<p class=\"npf_link\" data-npf='{\"type\":\"link\",\"url\":\"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy\",\"display_url\":\"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy\",\"title\":\"Affirmation (2016)\",\"description\":\"Affirmation (2016) uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton wa\",\"site_name\":\"Vimeo\",\"poster\":[{\"media_key\":\"cd78c9656df6b9381417c980464efff7:86fa2ab3c65a5863-70\",\"type\":\"image/webp\",\"width\":1920,\"height\":1080}]}'><a href=\"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy\" target=\"_blank\">Affirmation (2016)</a></p><p>Affirmation <br>2016<br>Single channel video</p><p>Affirmation uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton was badly injured shooting this portion of the film and chose to keep the jarring moment of impact in the finished comedy.</p>",
        "tree_html": ""
    },
    "can_reply": false,
    "display_avatar": true
},
{
    "type": "video",
    "is_blocks_post_format": true,
    "blog_name": "jessicaharbydotcom",
    "id": 744393060798136300,
    "id_string": "744393060798136320",
    "is_blazed": false,
    "is_blaze_pending": false,
    "can_blaze": false,
    "post_url": "https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/post/744393060798136320/very-realistic-2021-single-channel-video-in-the",
    "slug": "very-realistic-2021-single-channel-video-in-the",
    "date": "2024-03-08 14:35:43 GMT",
    "timestamp": 1709908543,
    "state": "published",
    "format": "html",
    "reblog_key": "hpmXLQE1",
    "tags": [
        "very realistic"
    ],
    "short_url": "https://tmblr.co/ZXen9PfKdOjw8u00",
    "summary": "Very Realistic\n2021\nSingle channel video \nIn The Great Muppet Caper (1981), reporters Kermit, Fozzie, and Gonzo travel to London...",
    "should_open_in_legacy": false,
    "recommended_source": null,
    "recommended_color": null,
    "note_count": 0,
    "title": "",
    "body": "<figure class=\"tmblr-full tmblr-embed\" data-provider=\"vimeo\" data-url=\"https://vimeo.com/544276930?share=copy\" data-orig-width=\"540\" data-orig-height=\"304\"><iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/544276930?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;app_id=122963\" width=\"540\" height=\"304\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture; clipboard-write\" title=\"Very Realistic (2021)\"></iframe></figure><p>Very Realistic<br/>2021<br/>Single channel video </p><p>In The Great Muppet Caper (1981), reporters Kermit, Fozzie, and Gonzo travel to London to investigate a jewel theft. Whilst riding in a red double-decker bus over the Thames, the following exchange takes place:</p><p>Fozzie: Wow, look at the scenery!<br/>Gonzo: It’s very realistic.</p><p>It is 2021, we have lived/are living through a collective trauma and during a car ride the landscape turned to a throbbing reality and we secretly begged to be let back inside.</p>",
    "reblog": {
        "comment": "<p><figure class=\"tmblr-full tmblr-embed\" data-provider=\"vimeo\" data-url=\"https://vimeo.com/544276930?share=copy\" data-orig-width=\"540\" data-orig-height=\"304\"><iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/544276930?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;app_id=122963\" width=\"540\" height=\"304\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture; clipboard-write\" title=\"Very Realistic (2021)\"></iframe></figure><p>Very Realistic<br>2021<br>Single channel video </p><p>In The Great Muppet Caper (1981), reporters Kermit, Fozzie, and Gonzo travel to London to investigate a jewel theft. Whilst riding in a red double-decker bus over the Thames, the following exchange takes place:</p><p>Fozzie: Wow, look at the scenery!<br>Gonzo: It’s very realistic.</p><p>It is 2021, we have lived/are living through a collective trauma and during a car ride the landscape turned to a throbbing reality and we secretly begged to be let back inside.</p></p>",
        "tree_html": ""
    },
    "can_reply": false,
    "display_avatar": true
}
]
let filteredPosts = [];
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const parser = new DOMParser();

const setPostsByType = () => {
let doc;
let videoThumbnail = '';
for (let i = 0; i < allPosts.length; i++) {
    const item = allPosts[i];
    if (item.body) {
        doc = parser.parseFromString(item.body, 'text/html');
    }
    if (item.type.includes('video')) {
        let videoID = doc.querySelector('a')?.getAttribute('href')?.split('vimeo.com/')[1] 
        ||
        doc.querySelector('[data-url]')?.getAttribute('data-url')?.split('vimeo.com/')[1];
        if (videoID && videoID.includes('?')) {
            videoID = videoID.split('?')[0];
        }
        console.log(videoID);
        fetch(`https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/${videoID}.json`)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.text();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                const { thumbnail_large } = JSON.parse(data)[0];
                videoThumbnail = thumbnail_large + '.jpg';
                console.log(videoThumbnail);
                return videoThumbnail; // this is asynchronous so being returned after the rest of my function is processed
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    const postObject = {
        id: item.id,
        post_id: `postid__${item.id}`,
        body: item.body,
        video_thumbnail_id: videoThumbnail, // this is always empty due to the fetch being asynchronous
        type: item.type,
        tags: item.tags,
        date: item.date
    }
    filteredPosts.push(postObject);
}
};

setPostsByType();
output.textContent = JSON.stringify(filteredPosts, null, 4);
<pre class="output"></pre>



Sorry there is quite a lot of data, this is already a filtered set. There is also a JSFIDDLE here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/wrLpheok/ which contains a larger set of data.
I know the issue in that fetch is asynchronous, and that maps, for loops execute according to the event order. The id's of each video post get logged to the console but after the filteredPosts array has been pushed to.
Here is what I have tried:

Wrapping everything inside an async function.
Create a function which should return the postObject and execute that inside the fetch .then() function (but of course this is wrapped in an if statement so filters the items in the array based on post type)
Use a map instead of of a for loop.

I have seen more questions on SO where users want to call a fetch api endpoint first and then map items, but my issue is the other way around, I can only call the fetch function once I have iterated through each post body and it has met my condition.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Just use async/await, that will make your code more readable and manageable. Avoid .then() for complex logic.
const result = await Promise.all(items.map(async item => {...})); is a common pattern to transform an array with some async logic into a new one.
You also have an error when there's no item.body and you could try to call doc.querySelector on the doc being undefined.


const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const parser = new DOMParser();

const setPostsByType = () => {
  return Promise.all(allPosts.map(async item => {
      let videoThumbnail = null;
      if (item.type.includes('video')) {
          const doc = parser.parseFromString(item.body ?? '', 'text/html');
          let videoID = doc.querySelector('a')?.getAttribute('href')?.split('vimeo.com/')[1] 
          ||
          doc.querySelector('[data-url]')?.getAttribute('data-url')?.split('vimeo.com/')[1];
          if (videoID && videoID.includes('?')) {
              videoID = videoID.split('?')[0];
          }
          try{
            const [{thumbnail_large}]  = await fetch(`https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/${videoID}.json`).then(r=>r.json());
            videoThumbnail = thumbnail_large + '.jpg';
          }catch(e){ console.log(e) }
      }
      return {
          id: item.id,
          post_id: `postid__${item.id}`,
          body: item.body,
          video_thumbnail_id: videoThumbnail, // this is always empty due to the fetch being asynchronous
          type: item.type,
          tags: item.tags,
          date: item.date
      }
  }));
};

setPostsByType().then(filteredPosts => {
  output.textContent = JSON.stringify(filteredPosts, null, 4);
});
<pre class="output"></pre>
<script>
const allPosts=[{type:"image",is_blocks_post_format:!0,blog_name:"jessicaharbydotcom",id:0xa54f58f6dc28000,id_string:"744489834793566208",is_blazed:!1,is_blaze_pending:!1,can_blaze:!1,post_url:"https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/post/744489834793566208/shield-2018-wax-display-case-light-shield-is-a",slug:"shield-2018-wax-display-case-light-shield-is-a",date:"2024-03-09 16:13:54 GMT",timestamp:1710000834,state:"published",format:"html",reblog_key:"4O3x5WWb",tags:["shield"],note_count:0,title:"",body:'<div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="4032" data-orig-width="2640"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg" data-orig-height="4032" data-orig-width="2640" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s75x75_c1/eb876d72933b6138eeba73ca59499c3809975b61.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s100x200/21f86af6b60e44ba7d90090281dc1a1461494805.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s250x400/eba73e6b36bf95f9473e9276592794923583d9de.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s400x600/f202a41604edd3e6cfeee2f9457620bbc87accff.jpg 393w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s500x750/3def886512d22590bb2b72396d147cb8007ccd46.jpg 491w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s540x810/d83eb22083d9dafb4feae95e2f4a2ca0553e0ae8.jpg 530w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg 629w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s1280x1920/1c03d83fdad14df8334745de77595cd9d2215ce7.jpg 1257w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s2048x3072/ee6e6bf1448c6304fbf6cbed93062b9ca520baf3.jpg 2011w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"/></figure></div><p>Shield<br/>2018<br/>Wax, display case, light</p><p>Shield is a meditation on masculinity and power. The tiles are wax casts of the substantial belt buckle once belonging to the artist&rsquo;s grandfather, who was a Chicago Police Sergeant investigated in the 1970s as part of a ring of police shaking down motorists for payoffs. While eventually granted immunity from prosecution by the state, he was indicted, along with two fellow policemen, for perjury by a grand jury for lying about his involvement.</p>',reblog:{comment:'<p><div class="npf_row"><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="4032" data-orig-width="2640"><img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg" data-orig-height="4032" data-orig-width="2640" srcset="https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s75x75_c1/eb876d72933b6138eeba73ca59499c3809975b61.jpg 75w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s100x200/21f86af6b60e44ba7d90090281dc1a1461494805.jpg 100w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s250x400/eba73e6b36bf95f9473e9276592794923583d9de.jpg 250w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s400x600/f202a41604edd3e6cfeee2f9457620bbc87accff.jpg 393w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s500x750/3def886512d22590bb2b72396d147cb8007ccd46.jpg 491w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s540x810/d83eb22083d9dafb4feae95e2f4a2ca0553e0ae8.jpg 530w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s640x960/d85c9c2f7f4ff41832f548cc2cac89905e6fe01b.jpg 629w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s1280x1920/1c03d83fdad14df8334745de77595cd9d2215ce7.jpg 1257w, https://64.media.tumblr.com/49d61fefb0215ba9d4b0af70a6e5c688/2c5835b67d79732a-9a/s2048x3072/ee6e6bf1448c6304fbf6cbed93062b9ca520baf3.jpg 2011w" sizes="(max-width: 1280px) 100vw, 1280px"></figure></div><p>Shield<br>2018<br>Wax, display case, light</p><p>Shield is a meditation on masculinity and power. The tiles are wax casts of the substantial belt buckle once belonging to the artist’s grandfather, who was a Chicago Police Sergeant investigated in the 1970s as part of a ring of police shaking down motorists for payoffs. While eventually granted immunity from prosecution by the state, he was indicted, along with two fellow policemen, for perjury by a grand jury for lying about his involvement.</p></p>',tree_html:""},can_reply:!1,display_avatar:!0},{type:"video video-embed",is_blocks_post_format:!0,blog_name:"jessicaharbydotcom",id:0xa54f2112ec38000,id_string:"744485994035904513",is_blazed:!1,is_blaze_pending:!1,can_blaze:!1,post_url:"https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/post/744485994035904513/referendum-ask-me-how-do-i-feel",slug:"referendum-ask-me-how-do-i-feel",date:"2024-03-09 15:12:51 GMT",timestamp:1709997171,state:"published",format:"html",reblog_key:"qL2EmJnA",tags:["referendum"],short_url:"https://tmblr.co/ZXen9PfKyX4kmu01",summary:"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)",should_open_in_legacy:!1,recommended_source:null,recommended_color:null,note_count:0,title:"",body:'<p class="npf_link" data-npf=\'{"type":"link","url":"https://vimeo.com/181950781","display_url":"https://vimeo.com/181950781","title":"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)","description":"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) uses footage from the classic film A Matter of Life and Death to create a new narrative. The film speaks d","site_name":"Vimeo","poster":[{"media_key":"ad17645e0781329536708048ee806163:9100d8a78851c197-1c","type":"image/webp","width":1920,"height":1080}]}\'><a href="https://vimeo.com/181950781" target="_blank">Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)</a></p><p>Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) <br/>2016<br/>Single channel video</p><p>Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) uses footage from the classic film A Matter of Life and Death to create a new narrative, speaking directly to the viewer as the men onscreen debate and decide important matters, failing to provide answers to the direct questions posed. </p>',reblog:{comment:'<p class="npf_link" data-npf=\'{"type":"link","url":"https://vimeo.com/181950781","display_url":"https://vimeo.com/181950781","title":"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)","description":"Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) uses footage from the classic film A Matter of Life and Death to create a new narrative. The film speaks d","site_name":"Vimeo","poster":[{"media_key":"ad17645e0781329536708048ee806163:9100d8a78851c197-1c","type":"image/webp","width":1920,"height":1080}]}\'><a href="https://vimeo.com/181950781" target="_blank">Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel)</a></p><p>Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) <br>2016<br>Single channel video</p><p>Referendum (Ask Me How Do I Feel) uses footage from the classic film A Matter of Life and Death to create a new narrative, speaking directly to the viewer as the men onscreen debate and decide important matters, failing to provide answers to the direct questions posed. </p>',tree_html:""},can_reply:!1,display_avatar:!0},{type:"video video-embed",is_blocks_post_format:!0,blog_name:"jessicaharbydotcom",id:0xa549dbae4120000,id_string:"744393264438837248",is_blazed:!1,is_blaze_pending:!1,can_blaze:!1,post_url:"https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/post/744393264438837248/affirmation-2016",slug:"affirmation-2016",date:"2024-03-08 14:38:57 GMT",timestamp:1709908737,state:"published",format:"html",reblog_key:"jniGZGhJ",tags:["affirmation"],short_url:"https://tmblr.co/ZXen9PfKdRha4W00",summary:"Affirmation (2016)",should_open_in_legacy:!1,recommended_source:null,recommended_color:null,note_count:0,title:"",body:'<p class="npf_link" data-npf=\'{"type":"link","url":"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy","display_url":"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy","title":"Affirmation (2016)","description":"Affirmation (2016) uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton wa","site_name":"Vimeo","poster":[{"media_key":"cd78c9656df6b9381417c980464efff7:86fa2ab3c65a5863-70","type":"image/webp","width":1920,"height":1080}]}\'><a href="https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy" target="_blank">Affirmation (2016)</a></p><p>Affirmation <br/>2016<br/>Single channel video</p><p>Affirmation uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton was badly injured shooting this portion of the film and chose to keep the jarring moment of impact in the finished comedy.</p>',reblog:{comment:'<p class="npf_link" data-npf=\'{"type":"link","url":"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy","display_url":"https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy","title":"Affirmation (2016)","description":"Affirmation (2016) uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton wa","site_name":"Vimeo","poster":[{"media_key":"cd78c9656df6b9381417c980464efff7:86fa2ab3c65a5863-70","type":"image/webp","width":1920,"height":1080}]}\'><a href="https://vimeo.com/153949952?share=copy" target="_blank">Affirmation (2016)</a></p><p>Affirmation <br>2016<br>Single channel video</p><p>Affirmation uses footage from the 1923 Buster Keaton film Three Ages as the basis for a guided meditation in vulnerability. Keaton was badly injured shooting this portion of the film and chose to keep the jarring moment of impact in the finished comedy.</p>',tree_html:""},can_reply:!1,display_avatar:!0},{type:"video",is_blocks_post_format:!0,blog_name:"jessicaharbydotcom",id:0xa549d8b7a238000,id_string:"744393060798136320",is_blazed:!1,is_blaze_pending:!1,can_blaze:!1,post_url:"https://jessicaharbydotcom.tumblr.com/post/744393060798136320/very-realistic-2021-single-channel-video-in-the",slug:"very-realistic-2021-single-channel-video-in-the",date:"2024-03-08 14:35:43 GMT",timestamp:1709908543,state:"published",format:"html",reblog_key:"hpmXLQE1",tags:["very realistic"],short_url:"https://tmblr.co/ZXen9PfKdOjw8u00",summary:"Very Realistic\n2021\nSingle channel video \nIn The Great Muppet Caper (1981), reporters Kermit, Fozzie, and Gonzo travel to London...",should_open_in_legacy:!1,recommended_source:null,recommended_color:null,note_count:0,title:"",body:'<figure class="tmblr-full tmblr-embed" data-provider="vimeo" data-url="https://vimeo.com/544276930?share=copy" data-orig-width="540" data-orig-height="304"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/544276930?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;app_id=122963" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture; clipboard-write" title="Very Realistic (2021)"></iframe></figure><p>Very Realistic<br/>2021<br/>Single channel video </p><p>In The Great Muppet Caper (1981), reporters Kermit, Fozzie, and Gonzo travel to London to investigate a jewel theft. Whilst riding in a red double-decker bus over the Thames, the following exchange takes place:</p><p>Fozzie: Wow, look at the scenery!<br/>Gonzo: It’s very realistic.</p><p>It is 2021, we have lived/are living through a collective trauma and during a car ride the landscape turned to a throbbing reality and we secretly begged to be let back inside.</p>',reblog:{comment:'<p><figure class="tmblr-full tmblr-embed" data-provider="vimeo" data-url="https://vimeo.com/544276930?share=copy" data-orig-width="540" data-orig-height="304"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/544276930?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;app_id=122963" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture; clipboard-write" title="Very Realistic (2021)"></iframe></figure><p>Very Realistic<br>2021<br>Single channel video </p><p>In The Great Muppet Caper (1981), reporters Kermit, Fozzie, and Gonzo travel to London to investigate a jewel theft. Whilst riding in a red double-decker bus over the Thames, the following exchange takes place:</p><p>Fozzie: Wow, look at the scenery!<br>Gonzo: It’s very realistic.</p><p>It is 2021, we have lived/are living through a collective trauma and during a car ride the landscape turned to a throbbing reality and we secretly begged to be let back inside.</p></p>',tree_html:""},can_reply:!1,display_avatar:!0}];
</script>




Thank you very much. I actually find the then() syntax more readable (I am more used to chaining) but I really appreciate your answer. A++
